# Finding the last record within three years of the first record with subqueries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, subquery

I have the following table with student enrollment data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Enrollments](
    [SequenceID] [bigint] NULL,
    [SchoolYear] [int] NULL,
    [StudentID] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [ProgramID] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [DepartureCode] [varchar](2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Enrollments] ([SequenceID], [SchoolYear], [StudentID], [ProgramID], [DepartureCode]) VALUES (29735, 2012, N'9800384', N'5331', N'10')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Enrollments] ([SequenceID], [SchoolYear], [StudentID], [ProgramID], [DepartureCode]) VALUES (33183, 2013, N'9800384', N'5331', N'01')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Enrollments] ([SequenceID], [SchoolYear], [StudentID], [ProgramID], [DepartureCode]) VALUES (33549, 2013, N'9800384', N'5331', N'01')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Enrollments] ([SequenceID], [SchoolYear], [StudentID], [ProgramID], [DepartureCode]) VALUES (37105, 2014, N'9800384', N'5331', N'01')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Enrollments] ([SequenceID], [SchoolYear], [StudentID], [ProgramID], [DepartureCode]) VALUES (37810, 2015, N'9800384', N'5331', N'22')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Enrollments] ([SequenceID], [SchoolYear], [StudentID], [ProgramID], [DepartureCode]) VALUES (29544, 2012, N'9100926', N'5729', N'01')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Enrollments] ([SequenceID], [SchoolYear], [StudentID], [ProgramID], [DepartureCode]) VALUES (37320, 2014, N'9100926', N'5729', N'01')
GO
```

I want to

1. Find the first year that the student was enrolled in a program.
2. Find the latest enrollment from all the enrollments occurring within 3 years of the first year.
3. Get the DepartureCode for the enrollment in 2.

Output for sample data above would be:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
| SequenceID   | SchoolYear   | StudentID    | ProgramID    | DepartureCode |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
|     37105    |         2014 |     9800384  |         5331 |           01  |
|     37320    |         2014 |     9100926  |         5729 |            01 |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+
```

This is the full record for the last enrollment within 3 years of the first enrollment.

I'm doing this with subqueries as below, but wondering if there is another way that is easier to read?

```
SELECT
    MainQueryEnrollments .StudentID,
    MainQueryEnrollments .ProgramID,
    MainQueryEnrollments .SchoolYear,
    MainQueryEnrollments .DepartureCode
FROM
    Enrollments AS MainQueryEnrollments
JOIN
    ( -- find SequenceID of the last enrollment within 
      -- three years of the first enrollment
    SELECT
        SubQueryEnrollments.StudentID,
        SubQueryEnrollments.ProgramID,
        MAX(SubQueryEnrollments SequenceID) AS SequenceID
    FROM
        Enrollments AS SubQueryEnrollments
    JOIN
        ( -- find the SchoolYear of the first enrollment
          SELECT
            StudentID,
            ProgramID,
            MIN(SchoolYear) AS SchoolYear
        FROM Enrollments
        GROUP BY
            StudentID,
            ProgramID
        ) FirstEnrollment
    ON FirstEnrollment.StudentID = SubQueryEnrollments.StudentID
    AND FirstEnrollment.ProgramID = SubQueryEnrollments.ProgramID
    AND SubQueryEnrollments.SchoolYear - FirstEnrollment.SchoolYear <= 2  
      -- enrollments within three years of the first enrollment
    GROUP BY
        SubQueryEnrollments .StudentID,
        SubQueryEnrollments .ProgramID
) AS LastEnrollment3Years
ON MainQueryEnrollments.SequenceID = LastEnrollment3Years.SequenceID
```

Comment: Do you have any indexes on this table? Do you have the ability to add/change them?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand I don't have any indexes but I do have the ability to add them.  I'm not so much concerned about performance as this is for an analytics application... data is loaded periodically (once a year) into PowerBI

Comment: Ok, so, if performance isn't important, and it only runs once a year, how do you define "better"?

Comment: Well, more concise I suppose.  When I have three layers of nested queries, I wonder if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: If you're just looking to make your query more readable, look at APPLY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution makes the following assumptions (*please let me know if I have misunderstood your requirements*)

1. `SequenceId` is like an Identity value and represents the chronological order of student changes.
2. You want to find the enrollment row for each student where the `SequenceId` is the `MAX(SequenceId)` for each student where the `SchoolYear` is within 3 years of the initial enrollment year for that student.

---

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Enrollments];
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Enrollments](
    [SequenceID] [bigint] NULL,
    [SchoolYear] [int] NULL,
    [StudentID] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [ProgramID] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [DepartureCode] [varchar](2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Enrollments] ([SequenceID], [SchoolYear], [StudentID], [ProgramID], [DepartureCode]) VALUES (29735, 2012, N'9800384', N'5331', N'10')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Enrollments] ([SequenceID], [SchoolYear], [StudentID], [ProgramID], [DepartureCode]) VALUES (33183, 2013, N'9800384', N'5331', N'01')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Enrollments] ([SequenceID], [SchoolYear], [StudentID], [ProgramID], [DepartureCode]) VALUES (33549, 2013, N'9800384', N'5331', N'01')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Enrollments] ([SequenceID], [SchoolYear], [StudentID], [ProgramID], [DepartureCode]) VALUES (37105, 2014, N'9800384', N'5331', N'01')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Enrollments] ([SequenceID], [SchoolYear], [StudentID], [ProgramID], [DepartureCode]) VALUES (37810, 2015, N'9800384', N'5331', N'22')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Enrollments] ([SequenceID], [SchoolYear], [StudentID], [ProgramID], [DepartureCode]) VALUES (29544, 2012, N'9100926', N'5729', N'01')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Enrollments] ([SequenceID], [SchoolYear], [StudentID], [ProgramID], [DepartureCode]) VALUES (37320, 2014, N'9100926', N'5729', N'01')
GO

;

WITH YearFirstEnrolled
AS (
    SELECT StudentID
        ,min(SchoolYear) AS YearFirstEnrolled
    FROM Enrollments
    GROUP BY StudentID
    )
SELECT *
FROM YearFirstEnrolled fe
JOIN Enrollments e
    ON e.StudentID = fe.StudentID
        AND e.SequenceID = (
            SELECT max(SequenceID)
            FROM Enrollments
            WHERE StudentID = e.StudentID
                AND SchoolYear < fe.YearFirstEnrolled + 3
            )
order by e.SequenceID
```

---

```
| StudentID | YearFirstEnrolled | SequenceID | SchoolYear | StudentID | ProgramID | DepartureCode |
|-----------|-------------------|------------|------------|-----------|-----------|---------------|
| 9800384   | 2012              | 37105      | 2014       | 9800384   | 5331      | 01            |
| 9100926   | 2012              | 37320      | 2014       | 9100926   | 5729      | 01            |
```

---

Select your desired columns from the result.